# Function to return a lock guard wrapping a private mutex

Tags: c++11, mutex

I have a simple class with the following declared privately:

```
std::mutex headMutex;  
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> usingHeadNode(){return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(headMutex);}
```

my aim is to provide a simple helper function that returns a unique_lock wrapping the mutex, so that my calling code can be

```
auto headGuard = usingHeadNode();
```

to lock the mutex with the RAII technique. However compiling this raises an error:

> error: use of deleted function
> ‘std::lock_guard<_Mutex>::lock_guard(const std::lock_guard<_Mutex>&)
> [with _Mutex = std::mutex]

... which looks like the constructor for the lock_guard class is missing or something? I haven't deleted anything as far as I'm aware...

---

Update for more context:

My simple class is a linked list, I want to add a node which involves overwriting the saved head pointer, so I believe I need to lock it to make it safe to modify. A snippet from that add function (can't share the full code as it's an assignment):

```
// [...]
Node * pNewNode = new Node(value);
    
//Link it in by prepending
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> pHeadGuard(headMutex); //= usingHeadNode();
pNewNode->prev = nullptr; //since we prepend and this is the new head, there is no 'previous' element
pNewNode->next = pHead; //what was the head now comes after the new node
// [...]

pHead = pNewNode; // this is why we needed the mutex
```

and I'd like to change the locking line to something more readable by wrapping it in a function call somehow

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that [`std::unique_lock` is *movable* but not *copyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock).  Knowing that about the semantics you can see why your code doesn't work - and what's more, you can decide if this technique is appropriate, or, possibly, prone to error.

Comment: Updated the code to clarify. So IIUC `return obj` actually copies the obj rather than returning a reference to it, and copying is not permitted for this type, is that correct? I want the scoped auto memory management of unique::lock, is there a way of creating it in the scope of the calling function so it is auto terminated at the end?

Comment: You say your "class is a linked list" by which I think (I hope) you mean you've properly encapsulated the linked list data structure along with the methods to manipulate it in the way you want inside your class.  If that's the case there's no advantage in maintainability or readability in using the lock that way (returning it from a function).  Just create it in place each time.  That's the canonical way, and everyone will understand it, and you will too.

Comment: In C++11 the "move" at the return isn't automatic, I think, it's up to the compiler.  Because of that it must be copyable, which it isn't.  In C++17 that's greatly improved and the move is required so this would probably "work" in the sense that it would compile.  (I think.  You can try on wandbox or godbolt if you like.)